# Доступ через службу samba к файлам с различными атрибутами

Tags: linux, samba

У меня есть сервер 1С на Ubuntu server 16.04.
На нём переодически делается синхронизация в 1С, после чего 1С формирует на сервере файл:
/data/sync/Message_I_AI.xml вот с такими атрибутами:

```
-rw-r----- 1 usr1cv8 grp1cv8 17995630 фев 8 11:52 Message_I_AI.xml
```

Этот файл пользователям локалки нужно скачать и отправить бугалтеру.
Для этого я установил samba и дал полный доступ к папке /data/sync/
Но получилось следущее - они видят этот файл но скачать не могут, хотя могут его удалить. Как мне пользователям дать доступ для чтения этого файла?

smb.conf

```
[shared]
comment = Public Folder
path = /data/sync
public = yes
writable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = yes
create mask = 0777
directory mask = 0777
```

Comment: Покажите конфиг самбы в части, которая описывает вашу шару.

Comment: [shared]

comment = Public Folder

path = /data/sync

public = yes

writable = yes

read only = no

guest ok = yes

create mask = 0777

directory mask = 0777

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
force group = grp1cv8
```

Надо добавить